# Connect to a computer in windows explorer, appears blank

Tags: windows, networking, lan

I have a windows 10 laptop

I am connecting to a lan computer, and when I go to the link   \192.168.2.122\,  it connects, asks for a password, and then appears blank.

I can, however view other network computers with the laptop, and ping the laptop

Comment: Are you sure the target computer actually has folders shared on the network?

Comment: Yes, I made sure to share the folders, and I use norton, so I enabled network sharing

Comment: Try connecting \\192.168.2.122\folder_share   Windows 10 need the folder share to be named

Comment: @John I tried \\192.168.2.122\users, but it came up with a error

Comment: Please open a Command Prompt and enter NET USE T: \\192.168.2.122\username and then please let us know what error number you get.

Comment: @john, It returned: network path is not found

Comment: I use \username without "users" because "users" is already shared and Active Directory knows about the "username" registered  (I also use the fully qualified name rather that IP)

Comment: "System error 53 has occurred."
The network path was not found @John

Comment: What happens if you go to the target computer itself and try to list its own shares? Try using \\hostname as well as \\192.168.2.122. Try the loopback IP address also: \\127.0.0.1 All three of these should work.

Comment: it opens a empty folder, too

Comment: System Error 53 suggests File/Print sharing or firewall error. Please see this article about this error:  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-networking/system-error-53-has-occurred-the-network-path-was/9511bbd8-ca11-4c1e-8d85-f7e8ce7e0fb9

Comment: Ok you're getting closer now. Try opening Command Prompt on the target laptop and running *net share*. Does it list any shares?

Comment: @wrecclesham ot lists 
C:\
C:\WINDOWS\system32\spool\drivers
C:\WINDOWS

Comment: Great. We've narrowed this issue down to the target laptop. The shares you are expecting to see don't exist. c:\users isn't shared. Do you definitely see that sharing is enabled on that folder if you check it directly?

Comment: Update: I was able to share the C drive, by right clicking OS (C), click Give access to, and sharing. The issue is now, that it appears as a share of 192.168.2.122, but not as 192.168.2.122 itself. @wrecclesham

Comment: That's what you would expect to see! A UNC path is always in the format \\servername\sharename  Even if you share the root of your entire C drive, that share still appears after the backslash after the address of the target laptop, not "within" it. You would expect to see something along the lines of: \\TargetLaptop\CDriveShareName

Comment: ooohhh.... Thanks so much

Comment: want to post the link as a answer so I can mark it correct?

Comment: The *net share* command was how you solved this. There's no mention of that command on that generic Windows Vista network troubleshooting page. I've posted it as an answer to help others in future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was essentially solved by performing the following three steps:

1. Ran `net share` on target laptop to verify what shares actually existed
2. Confirmed that the expected shared folder did not exist
3. Created the required share on the target laptop

[image]

Answer (score 1):

System Error 53 suggests File/Print sharing or firewall error.

Please see this article about this error:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-networking/system-error-53-has-occurred-the-network-path-was/9511bbd8-ca11-4c1e-8d85-f7e8ce7e0fb9